# Unable to recover deleted records from a table in a database with no backup in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, data-recovery

I have accidently deleted some records from the production database in the morning. I do not have backup. i tried this link 
[`http://raresql.com/2011/10/22/how-to-recover-deleted-data-from-sql-sever/`][1]

and i got the records in local i got the records.
But, issue arised when i tried this in the afternoon.
**Is it like the transaction log file shows only recent activity records?** 
If so, what could be the possible time interval?
And what if i have to recover older records?

Please, guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: Without a backup, the transaction log will be in simple mode - meaning that the existing log records can be overwritten at any time. The simple rule is that you should never rely on such mechanisms but should have a proper backup / restore process defined, based on the business restore SLA requirements. Go talk to your DBA and say sorry for doing things on production servers. If you are the DBA and do not have a backup of production... you may need to update your resume.

Comment: @Andrew..I appreciate.

Comment: So in short,the transaction log got overwritten somehow and now i cannot get back the older records..right?

Comment: Correct, the rows are now gone.

Answer (score 0):

The transaction log is a cyclic log. You can google the working of sql server transaction log.

But getting straight to the answer, the transaction log gets overwritten when a checkpoint occurs,so the old records are overwritten.

You can take the transaction log backups by putting the database in full recovery mode but remember to take the transaction log backups as the logs will grow in size till you take a log backup which will result in hard disk space issue and also the data going into suspect mode in a worst case scenario.